Refunding a REST API-captured payment using NVP?
I'm trying to implement refunds for payments captured using the REST API's "capture payment" functionality. I'm saving the transaction ID for reference.
My question is: can I use NVP for refunds in this scenario, or do I need to switch to the REST API for refunds as well?
I couldn't find this information in the documentation. Currently, my refunds are handled through NVP, but I'm moving to using the REST API for order creation and capture. Ideally, I'd like to use the saved transaction ID from the capture process to initiate the refund via NVP.
Is this approach feasible, or is using the REST API mandatory for refunds initiated after a REST API capture?

Yes, it is possible to use the legacy NVP/SOAP RefundTransaction API operation to refund a capture ID that was created using a REST API. You can test this in the PayPal sandbox.

Thank you! Is it also possible to do it the other way around? Specifically, if I make a payment using NVP, can I issue a refund using the REST API?

Also testable in sandbox, but yes it works.
